# How I can modify my env properties files in GIT by Jenkins parameter

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Here is my UseCase.
In my project, we have 5 different environments SIT1, SIT2, UAT1, UAT2 & PROD which are in Git repo. All environments having specific properties files like sit1.properties file and so on. In each property file, we have a property called **user.access** which will have the consumer's name for authentication purposes.

```
user.access= user1,user2
```

So, I need to create a Jenkins job that will add a new username to user.access property which I pass in the build parameter. For example, if I have 3 parameters in the Jenkins job

```
applicationName = abc
enviornment = sit1
userid = user3
```

Then it will update my sit1.properties file with the user.access= user1,user2,user3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I follow "environments" idea here. I assume you clone git repo and you have some dir structure you can use. Anyway, when file you want to update is there in your workspace, you can do:

```
pipeline{
    parameters { string(name: 'userid', defaultValue: 'test1', description: '') }
    agent {label 'master'}
    stages{
        stage('1'){
            steps{
                script{
                    // read content to map
                   Map content = readProperties file: "a.properties"
                   List userAccessValue = content["user.access"].tokenize(",")
                   // modify desired value
                   userAccessValue.add(params.userid)
                   // modify map
                   content["user.access"]=userAccessValue.join(",")
                   // recreate content: convert map to list and then to string separating each key=value with OS line separator
                   String listAsString = content.collect().join(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
                   // write everything back, overwriting previous content
                   writeFile file: "a.properties", text: listAsString
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have few properties files you can use dir directive:

```
dir("dir1/location1"){
// read content to map
Map content = readProperties file: "a.properties"
...
}
dir("dir2/location2"){
// read content to map
Map content = readProperties file: "a.properties"
...
}
```

or you can create dedicated method to navigate to specific directories and overwrite file (overwriteFile is of course the code I gave in the first example):

```
pipeline{
    parameters { string(name: 'userid', defaultValue: 'test1', description: '') }
    agent {label 'master'}
    stages{
        stage('1'){
            steps{
                script{
                    multipleOverwrite(["dir1/location1", "dir2/location2"])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def multipleOverwrite(list){
    list.each{loc ->
        dir(loc){
            overwriteFile("a.properties")
        }
    }
}
```